Is it possible to create server running inside of flutter app and access it from any device/network (Not only locally)?
I am trying to build Flutter app that would have two phones connected: Server and Client. I found examples where phones connect within local network, but I can't understand how to allow connection from other networks (Example: Phone 1 (Host) - WiFi, Phone 2 (Client) - Cellular network). Is it possible to do? How can I do it?
I tried to create simple server/client application using flutter, but I couldn't figure out how to establish connection between phones in different networks (From other device in another network, not locally within one WiFi).

For that you need to connect them via internet and have some common database between them

@JunaidKhalid if I want to store data on one device and then request it via internet, how can I do it? Basically my goal is to have Server on one phone with data stored and then another phone on another network requesting data as Client. Is it possible to achieve somehow?
